# Overfull hbox in author list in acmart + texlive 2020

Tags: acmart, texlive-2020

There is a peculiar overfull hbox that seems to arise from the `authornotemark` in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,nonacm]{acmart}
\title{Test}
\author{A}
\authornotemark
\affiliation{\institution{T}\country{R}}
\author{B}
\affiliation{\institution{T}\country{R}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

(pdf)latex reports an

> Overfull \hbox (4.18721pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--11

I have not found anything useful in the log regarding this. The overfull hbox happens when there is an `authornotemark` after the first of the two authors; it also occurs with more authors. Just adding a `footnotemark` in the author’s name is fine, though.
My local version is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03>
Document Class: acmart 2020/11/15 v1.75 Typesetting articles for the Association for Computing Machinery
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
```

No overfull hbox is reported on overleaf, with

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.10)  28 NOV 2020 01:21
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17>
Document Class: acmart 2020/04/30 v1.71 Typesetting articles for the Association for Computing Machinery
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
```

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this further, and I’m curious as to why this can happen.

Comment: the difference is the new acmart.cls has `\RequirePackage{hyerxmp}` without that the ovefull box goes, but haven't traced exactly whatis happening yet

Comment: the warning is spurious in that the actual shipped out page does not contain the overfull box, the new code is doing some trial typesetting somewhere and you are seeing a warning from a discarded box, but still not sure where:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the newest `acmart.cls` loads `hyperxmp` and that has some acmart-specific code to try to parse metadata from the class-specific title commands.

At one point the authors are set in a box and this results in the overfull box message but this box is just used for some internal checks and never output to the page, so the warning does not in fact relate to any over full output in the document.

It seems very dubious that the generic hyperxmp package is requiring acmart-specific code but the simplest fix is just to silence warnings while doing the trial typesetting

line 596 of hyperxmp.sty is

```
    \setbox0=\hbox{\addresses}%
```

changing it to

```
   \setbox0=\hbox{\hfuzz\maxdimen\addresses}%
```

silences the warning. You could raise this with the hyperxmp author.